# C# Cleanly assign every method parameter a single value

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, c#-4.0

I created a function(shown below) to assign the text of 9 buttons all to " "(I generally try to use " " instead of assigning a variable to null out of some illogical assumption, so I would appreciate it to be pointed out if I'm incorrect), but I feel like I could've assigned every parameter to a blank string in a cleaner way.

```
 public void resetText(ref string buttonText1, ref string buttonText2, ref string buttonText3, ref string buttonText4, ref string buttonText5, ref string buttonText6, ref string buttonText7, ref string buttonText8, ref string buttonText9)
    {
        buttonText1 = "";
        buttonText2 = "";
        buttonText3 = "";
        buttonText4 = "";
        buttonText5 = "";
        buttonText6 = "";
        buttonText7 = "";
        buttonText8 = "";
        buttonText9 = "";
    }
```

Is there a cleaner/shorter way to reassign every parameter. This would look pretty bad if I were to have to assign 50 variables a new value in this function(I just used buttons as an example.)

Comment: Doesn't appear that there is a cleaner way to do this. But maybe the parent function could do this better by keeping the text values in an array.

Comment: So there is no way that you know of to just loop through all the parameters and assign them a null value, or something similar?

Comment: Can be updated as: `buttonText1 = buttonText2 = buttonText3 = buttonText4 = buttonText5 = buttonText6= buttonText7 = buttonText8 = buttonText9 = string.Empty; `

Comment: @zzT That does look a bit cleaner, but still not exactly shorter/ clean.

Comment: The problem is that the paramaters are marked as `ref`. Otherwise you could do a `param[]` declaration and iterate through it using a loop.

Comment: @EmmanuelMathi-Amorim well I pretty much have to use ref, unless theres some other simple way to reassign the actual reference, and not a copy, and I guess I should avoid making something more complex than it needs to be.

Comment: This appears to be a [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) type problem.  You have a method that presumably resets the text property of a control by referencing its Text property.  A simpler solution would be to send the controls themselves to the method to be acted on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty much the best way to do this. It is simple and easy to read.

You can do something like this `buttonText1 = buttonText2 = buttonText3 = ... = "";` if you really want to reduce character count.

Another way of reducing the code size is to do it by reflection. I would not recommend going this way since it makes the code overly complicated for saving just a few characters.